# How do I filter out messages sent from Gmail from the "Comment Save" Google Chrome Extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

Extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ndmcbhmmonjkclhmeidccodfhlifmmco

I did include "gmail.com" in the filters, but it still doesn't leave out stuff from Gmail.

Here are the filter instructions:

> Filters allow you to disable tracking on websites. Enter filters into
>   the box below (one per line).  For example, if you don't want your
>   comments on Facebook tracked enter "facebook.com" (without the
>   quotes).

I'll try including `mail.google.com` in the filter as well. But are there any other alternative filter suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I am the author of the extension. I realize it can be annoying to have all your gmail emails/chats be stored on there, but as of now the only way to filter it out is to explicitly add "mail.google.com" in there.

Comment: Could you provide/edit in a link to this extension into the original question just for clarity's sake?